# resize an image with ImageMagick

Tags: resize, imagemagick

I want to resize the img to 90x90 by using the following code but the img is uploaded but is not resize..

```
    $image = 'the path to the img';
 /*** a new imagick object ***/
        $im = new Imagick();

        /*** ping the image ***/
        $im->pingImage($image);

        /*** read the image into the object ***/
        $im->readImage( $image );

        $im->thumbnailImage( 90, null );

        $im->setImageFormat( "png" );

        /*** write image to disk ***/
        $im->writeImage( "tmp/spork.png" );

        $im->destroy();
```

I change the code to `$im->cropThumbnailImage(90,90);` but still it dosent work.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that stands out to me in the code you posted, however looking at the manual page for thumbnailImage, a lot of the comments suggest other approaches which are claimed to be better for various reasons:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.thumbnailimage.php

Answer (score 0):

On the website you found the code there is a method to display any errors using try and catch; add those and see if you get an error.

Is the save folder really tmp? Is it CHMOD 755 or 777?

Comment: the img is uploaded to that folder but is not resized. And there is no errors

Comment: If you change $im->writeImage( "tmp/spork.png" ); to $im->writeImage( "spork.png" ); the image should be in the same folder as the code

Comment: Out of interest you are using Imagick not Imagemagick directly.